# Install yarn denied

Tags: nestjs, yarnpkg

I've tried in command  "yarn global add @nestjs/cli"

but command return "zsh: command not found: yarn"

so I tried to install yarn "npm install -global yarn"

however, access denied

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmXLQ.png)

What should I do?

Comment: Which version of linux are You using  ?

Answer (score 1):

First check who is the owner of the directory =>

```
ls -la /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn
```

then change owner to Yourself

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn
```

Then try again, you shouldn't have any problems with this error.

```
npm install --global yarn
```

*you may need to use `sudo` before npm*

```
sudo npm install --global yarn
```

Comment: @AlfaDcz try sudo npm install --global yarn

Comment: OH PERFECT! IT WORKS WITH sudo npm install --global yarn
Thank you so much my hero :)

Comment: @AlfaDcz  I am Happy for that ;-) Glad I could Help You :-* -D

Comment: @AlfaDcz Take a look here => https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5865 I think this is your remedy

Comment: Thanks my hero :)

Comment: @AlfaDcz You're welcome my lady :-) :-D !!!

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this!

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules

sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/bin

npm install -g yarn
```